# std::vector segfaulting instead of throwing exception

Tags: c++, vector, exception, segmentation-fault

I am attempting to create a container class for a `std::vector`, to teach myself a bit more about templates, overloading operators, and managing exceptions.

For the moment, I'm just defining the basic operations.  I have a template class listed below; I've overloaded the `+=` and `[]` operators to `push_back` the `vector` with a `T` and access the elements of the vector directly, respectively. This works as expected.

The `+=` operator does what it's supposed to do, and attempting to use the `[]` operator on an element out of range will throw the exception as intended.

Here is the prototype class and implementation as it currently stands:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Inventory
{
    public:
        void operator += (const T& b)   { backpack.push_back(b); }

        T operator [] (const unsigned& b)
        {
            if (backpack.empty() || backpack.size() < b)
                throw string("Out of Range");
            return backpack[b];
        }

        void operator -= (const unsigned& b)
        {
            if (backpack.empty() || backpack.size() < b)
                throw string("No such element exists.");
            backpack.erase(backpack.begin() + b);
        }

    private:
        vector<int> backpack;
};

int main()
{
    Inventory<int> pack;
    pack += 2;
    pack += 4;
    try
    {
        cout << "It was " << pack[0] << endl;
        cout << "It was " << pack[1] << endl;
        pack -= 0;
        cout << "It is now " << pack[0] << endl;
        //pack -= 1; // Segfaults?
    }
    catch (string e)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << e << endl;
    }
}
```

The issue is with the `-=` operator, intended to erase an element at the indicated position on the right hand side.  When I stay within the boundaries of the vector, this works as intended; however, I do not get an *exception* if I specify an out of bounds number to erase; I get a *seg-fault* instead. I have attempted to determine the exact point the segfault occurs by adding additional print commands:

```
void operator -= (const unsigned& b)
{
    cout << "In Overload!\n";
    if (backpack.empty() || backpack.size() < b)
    {
        cout << "Exception!\n";
        throw string("No such element exists.");
    }
    backpack.erase(backpack.begin() + b);
}
```

The "Exception!" line is never reached. The program faults before it can reach that point, even though I should be *evaluating* for undefined behavior. I believe I'm missing a key component in understanding how this process works. Is there a way I should be writing this so it can throw instead of fault?

Compiling using `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on Linux x64 architecture.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `std::vector::at()` instead of writing your own test for an invalid index?  The `vector::at()` is guaranteed to throw an `out_of_range` exception.

Comment: "The "Exception!" cout is never reached. The program faults before it can reach that point" - how do you know the program was going to reach that point? Maybe it went and called `backpack.erase`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie perhaps this is a coding exercise.

Comment: Indeed. I am self-teaching C++, as I mentioned. So when I go to learn a new concept, I tend to try to break the new things down into chunks. First I wrote this code specifically for ints. Then I turned it into a template. Then I added error handling and exception throwing. Next I'll be using the standard exceptions, adding feature methods, and so on. I find this makes it simpler for me to get my hands around new information without getting overwhelmed. Thank you for the reply though. I do appreciate it!

Comment: A few notes: The correct data type to index into containers is `size_t`, not `unsigned int` (although they may be the same on some implementations). And unless this is for learning, you probably shouldn't be catching this exception. There is nothing meaningful you can do to fix program state. It has run into an unexpected condition, and the only safe alternative is to have it terminate. By default, that's what happens when you encounter an uncaught exception.

Comment: Since you are learning: (1) catch by const-reference, unless you plan to modify and re-throw the exception in which case catch by reference (otherwise you might get truncation when the exception is a child class of what you catch); (2) do not use `std::endl` (it calls `flush` on the stream, slowing things down massively), just use `"\n"` instead; (3) design API with good taste: the fact that `+=` takes the element and `-=` takes the position is REALLY confusing. Use named methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your error checking is off by 1.

```
if (backpack.empty() || backpack.size() < b)
```

If the `std::vector` backpack contains only two values, `backpack.size()` is going to be 2, and `backpack` will contain `backpack[0]` and `backpack[1]`.

Unfortunately, if the index `b` gets passed in as 2, this code will still attempt to access `backpack[2]`, resulting in undefined behavior.

In fact, the entire `if` statement can be simply rewritten as:

```
if (b >= backpack.size())
    throw string("Out of Range");
```

Comment: Palm, meet face. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have an "off by one" error in your code.,

Consider what happens if the array is not empty and `b == backpack.size()` in the code.

```
 if (backpack.empty() || backpack.size() < b)
            throw string("Out of Range");
 return backpack[b];
```

In this case, valid indices for elements of `backpack` are `0` through to `backpack.size() - 1`.

If `b == backpack.size()`, the code will NOT throw an exception, and WILL attempt to return `backpack[backpack.size()]` which gives undefined behaviour.

One possible symptom of undefined behaviour is a "segfault".

One way to avoid the problem is to change the test to `backpack.size() <= b`.

Comment: Indeed. A few other people here have pointed out that exact problem. I've since corrected it. I do appreciate the feedback and help! Sometimes it's the simplest of oversights that can trip up a program, no? :)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to take advantage of [std::vector::at()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) which will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception on an out-of-bounds index:

```
    T operator [] (const unsigned& b)
    {
        try 
        {
           return backpack.at(b);
        }
        catch (std::out_of_range& e)
        {
            throw string("Out of Range");
        }
    }

    void operator -= (const unsigned& b)
    {
        try
        {
            backpack.at(b);
            backpack.erase(backpack.begin() + b);
        }
        catch(std::out_of_range& e)
        {
           throw std::string("No such element exists.");
        }
    }
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/G7dmVd)

Comment: That looks great! I really appreciate you pointing that out. Part of the issue with self-teaching is that it's easy to miss little things like that. :)